# How to set "useAutomationExtension" to false in Chromedriver 79

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

My goal is to get webpage HTML automatically (without any other actions).
I'm trying to disable Automation Extension for ChromeDriver 79 to avoid selenium detection.
As I know, it doesn't work after ChromeDriver 78. Is there a way to do it in version 79?

```
def get_chromedriver(path, use_proxy=False, user_agent=None):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    if use_proxy:
        pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'
        print("proxy")
        with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
            zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
            zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)
        chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    if user_agent:
        chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=%s' % user_agent)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        path,
        chrome_options=chrome_options)

    return driver
```

Comment: _...doesn't work after ChromeDriver 78..._ source of information or documentation?